# How to map an array of objects in a a new array with new key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a situation where I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Phone call",
        "value": "Phone call"
    },
    {
        "name": "SMS",
        "value": "SMS"
    },
    {
        "name": "Email",
        "value": "Email"
    }
]
```

I have to remap the above OBJ to a new one containing its translation which is similar to this from React-intl: `formatMessage(formatMessage(messages.emailOptionPlaceholder)`

And the idea is as follow:

```
if (obj.name === 'Email') formatMessage(formatMessage(messages.emailOptionPlaceholder) else obj.name
```

so the new array should contain the right translation which will populate a dropdown menu.

I tried so far like this but without success:

```
field.options.map(o => {
        return [
          o.name === 'Email'
            ? formatMessage(messages.emailOptionPlaceholder)
            : o.name,
          o.name === 'Phone call'
            ? formatMessage(messages.phoneOptionPlaceholder)
            : o.name,
          o.name === 'SMS'
            ? formatMessage(messages.smsOptionPlaceholder)
            : o.name,
        ];
      });
```

This gives back 3 arrays instead of one with the values I need.

My goal is to have an array containing the `formatMessage(...)` output for the 3 elemnts inside the object as example of the output:

```
[{
  name: Phone call
  value: <-- Phone call translation from formatMessage --> 
 }
{
  name: Email
  value: <-- Email translation from formatMessage --> 
 }
{
  name: SMS
  value: <-- SMS call translation from formatMessage --> 
 }
]
```

I'm getting that OBJ from back-end and need to put the translation of corresponding name inside a drop down menu and was wondering what solution can be better.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? With all the code involved. The return values form the function etc. are currently unclear.

Comment: That is because you are wrapping your return in an array `return [ ... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this. (not tested)

```
const mappings = {
    'Email': messages.emailOptionPlaceholder,
    'Phone call': messages.phoneOptionPlaceholder,
    'SMS': messages.smsOptionPlaceholder
};

const mapped = field.options.map((obj) => {
    const key = mappings[obj.name]
    if (key) {
        return {
            ...obj,
            value: formatMessages(key)
        }
    } else {
        // no mapping for object name.
        // do something to handle it or just return obj
        return obj
    }
}
```

If you are only interested in the values you can do this.

```
const mappings = {
    'Email': messages.emailOptionPlaceholder,
    'Phone call': messages.phoneOptionPlaceholder,
    'SMS': messages.smsOptionPlaceholder
};

const mapped = field.options.map((obj) => {
    const key = mappings[obj.name]
    return formatMessages(key) || key //
}
```

Comment: I tried this but how can I return only the value and use that to populate a drop down menu? asking becasue I see the translation but the drop-down is populated still with the English name and not arabic

Comment: How to populate depends on the nature of your dropdown and if you are using a frontend library. In vanilla HTML / js you will probably need to add the options with javascript.

But to only get the values in the array is straightforward. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using .map is a possible solution, however you are not using it correctly. [From mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

To fix your solution, you can use the following code:

```
field.options.map((o) => {
  if (o.name === "Email") {
    return { ...o, value: formatMessage(messages.emailOptionPlaceholder) };
  } else if (o.name === "Phone call") {
    return { ...o, value: formatMessage(messages.phoneOptionPlaceholder) };
  } else if (o.name === "SMS") {
    return { ...o, value: formatMessage(messages.smsOptionPlaceholder) };
  } else {
    return o;
  }
});
```

Note that .map returns a new array, so you need to save the result. If you want to mutate the objects directly, then use a simple forEach , like so:

```
field.options.forEach(o => {
      if (o.name === "Email") {
        o.value = formatMessage(messages.emailOptionPlaceholder);
      } else if (o.name === "Phone call") {
        o.value = formatMessage(messages.phoneOptionPlaceholder);
      } else if (o.name === "SMS") {
        o.value = formatMessage(messages.smsOptionPlaceholder);
      }
    })
```

Comment: Yes I need to add options to dropdown menu so I need the results to go there.
Maybe the foreach is not ok and better a map in my situation?